# Build Android AAR with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have created an Android library.  How do I build the project with gradle/gradlew to generate the AAR?

Currently I can only accomplish this by creating a dummy Android application, adding my library to it, and then using that project's gradlew to execute commands.

I have tried copying the gradle files from the dummy application to the android library project, but I get `Plugin [id: 'com.android.library'] was not found...`

The goal is to have an Jenkins job generate an AAR when a repo is updated.

Thanks for any advice/hints/answers in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else finds this question.  My only solution is to create the dummy app and the library project.  Then delete all the dummy app files you can until the only things left are the gradle files and the library files.